# Ubuntu: Flash Videos in Fullscreen Freeze

Tags: flash, firefox, ubuntu, fullscreen, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 on my IBM X200t. Installed is the standard flash player plugin for Firefox: (*flashplugin-nonfree*, 10.1.102.65). Everytime I switch a flash video to fullscreen, the video freezes. However, the video continues to play and I hear sound. How can I fix this?

Comment: That belongs to superuser.com.

Comment: Sorry. Nevertheless, I already fixed it: Deactivate all visual effects.

Comment: One for http://askubuntu.com/ , I reckon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer by mervin might work too, but i know for a fact that this thread worked: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10513659#post10513659

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in a terminal:

sudo mkdir /etc/adobe

sudo su

sudo echo \"OverrideGPUValidation = 1\" >> /etc/adobe/mms.cfg